# Getting individual pixels from touch point

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, touch, multi-touch

Is it possible to detect every pixel being touched? More specifically, when the user touches the screen, is it possible to track all the x-y coordinates of the cluster of points touched by the user? How can I tell the difference between when users are drawing with their thumb and when they are drawing with the tip of a finger? I would like to reflect the brush difference depending on how users touch the screen, and would also like to track all the pixels being touched.

I am currently using the following codes from the GLPaint sample from Apple developer site:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

The sample codes allow drawing with a predefined brush size and tracking the x-y coordinates along the way. How can I change the brush depending on how users touch the screen and track all the pixels being touched over time?

```
// Drawings a line onscreen based on where the user touches

- (void) renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end

{
     NSLog(@"x:%f   y:%f",start.x, start.y);

     static GLfloat*          vertexBuffer = NULL;

     static NSUInteger     vertexMax = 64;

     NSUInteger               vertexCount = 0,

                    count,

                    i;



     [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

     glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);



     // Convert locations from Points to Pixels

     CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;

     start.x *= scale;

     start.y *= scale;

     end.x *= scale;

     end.y *= scale;



     // Allocate vertex array buffer

     if(vertexBuffer == NULL)

          vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));



     // Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels

     count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);

     for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

          if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {

               vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;

               vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

          }



          vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);

          vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);

          vertexCount += 1;

     }



     // Render the vertex array

     glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

     glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);



     // Display the buffer

     glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

     [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];

}


// Handles the start of a touch

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

     CGRect                    bounds = [self bounds];

     UITouch*     touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];

     firstTouch = YES;

     // Convert touch point from UIView referential to OpenGL one (upside-down flip)

     location = [touch locationInView:self];

     location.y = bounds.size.height - location.y;

}

// Handles the continuation of a touch.

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{  

     CGRect                    bounds = [self bounds];

     UITouch*               touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];



     // Convert touch point from UIView referential to OpenGL one (upside-down flip)

     if (firstTouch) {

          firstTouch = NO;

          previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

          previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;

     } else {

          location = [touch locationInView:self];

         location.y = bounds.size.height - location.y;

          previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

          previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;

     }



     // Render the stroke

     [self renderLineFromPoint:previousLocation toPoint:location];

}



// Handles the end of a touch event when the touch is a tap.

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

     CGRect                    bounds = [self bounds];

    UITouch*     touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];

     if (firstTouch) {

          firstTouch = NO;

          previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

          previousLocation.y = bounds.size.height - previousLocation.y;

          [self renderLineFromPoint:previousLocation toPoint:location];

     }

}


// Handles the end of a touch event.

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

     // If appropriate, add code necessary to save the state of the application.

     // This application is not saving state.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no API to access the touch zone for a touch.  I'm not even sure, given the limits of a capacitive touch screen, whether what you want is physically possible.  I recall a presentation at a recent Cocoa Heads where it was demonstrated that some of the information was available on OS X (via private API) for trackpads, but not for iOS.

I believe this is one reason that graphics tablets employ special styluses that have their own sensor technology built in.

A partial workaround, for a drawing application, might be to simulate "inking" as some desktop applications do: if a user's touch lingers in a given spot, draw as if ink were coming out of the "pen" and gradually diffusing through the "paper."

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Do you know whether this is possible on Android?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry, I don't develop for Android.  I'm sure others will have an answer, though.  If you can't find anything on search, I suggest posting a new question tagged as Android.

Answer (score 1):

The Broadcomm hardware in the iPad scans the screen with 64 Hz. It does this by putting a signal consecutively for 400 µs each on the 39 transparent, conductive layers which constitute the touchscreen electrodes. If your finger moves by more than a pixel distance within 0.015625 sec, which is likely, the hardware cannot detect this because it is busy measuring other parts of the screen for more touch events.

This is the same regardless of iOS or Android. Cheap Android tablets and large screens have a reduced scan rate, so their touch events are even more widely spaced.

A Wacom tablet runs the digitizer at 100 Hz, so the sequence of points will be finer, but still will miss those pixels the stylus touches between two measurements.